How to preserve an informative `__init__` signature when using parameterized Mixins in Python?
In my Python project, I heavily use Mixins as a design pattern, and I’d like to continue doing so. However, I am facing an issue with the __init__ method signatures in the final class. Since I am passing arguments through **kwargs, the resulting signature is not helpful for introspection or documentation or type checking. Here’s an example to illustrate the issue:
class Base:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1

class ParamMixin1:
    def __init__(self, arg2, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.arg2 = arg2

class ParamMixin2:
    def __init__(self, arg3, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.arg3 = arg3

class NonParamMixin:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class Derived(NonParamMixin, ParamMixin1, ParamMixin2, Base):
    pass

d = Derived(arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=3)

from inspect import signature
print(signature(Derived.__init__))

This prints:
(self, **kwargs)

The signature is not very helpful since all arguments are hidden under **kwargs. I could technically rewrite the __init__ methods like this to expose the full signature:
class Base:
    def __init__(self, arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1

class ParamMixin1:
    def __init__(self, arg2, arg1):
        super().__init__(arg1)
        self.arg2 = arg2

class ParamMixin2:
    def __init__(self, arg3, arg2, arg1):
        super().__init__(arg2, arg1)
        self.arg3 = arg3

class NonParamMixin:
    def __init__(self, arg3, arg2, arg1):
        super().__init__(arg3, arg2, arg1)

class Derived(NonParamMixin, ParamMixin1, ParamMixin2, Base):
    pass

from inspect import signature
print(signature(Derived.__init__))

This works, and the signature is more informative, but it introduces a lot of boilerplate and requires the correct ordering of arguments, which sometimes doesn't matter depending on the mixins used. Furthermore sometimes only a subset of the mixins is used.
I've tried creating a metaclass to override the __init__ signature dynamically, but it became very messy, and I couldn’t get it to work reliably.
However, it feels counterintuitive not to have access to the proper __init__ signature. Without it, I’d need to manually track all the mixins and their required parameters, which seems impractical. Surely, there’s a better way to manage this?
Any suggestions or alternative approaches to achieve a cleaner, more maintainable solution would be greatly appreciated as well!

Maybe I got it wrong, but in one section of this question I understand you want a keyword argument, but in the second section you want to enforce 3-4 parameters for, let's say, NonParamMixin - if so - why use kwargs and not just enforce specific amount of arguments and their types?

super is designed around an inherently dynamic inheritance system. Without defining Derived.__init__ explicitly, you start with NonParamMix.__init__, and it can't know about how its own subclasses are using it.

from dataclasses import dataclass
from inspect import signature


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Base:
    arg1: int


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class ParamMixin1:
    arg2: int


@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class ParamMixin2:
    arg3: int


@dataclass
class NonParamMixin:
    pass


@dataclass
class Derived(NonParamMixin, ParamMixin1, ParamMixin2, Base):
    pass


d = Derived(arg1=1, arg2=2, arg3=3)
# d = Derived(1, 2, 3)  # raises an error because of kw_only=True

print(signature(Derived.__init__))
# (self, *, arg1: int, arg3: int, arg2: int) -> None
# * means that all the arguments after * are keyword-only arguments
# This way you don't have to worry about order


Yeah that would work. However I am kind of worrying to introduce dataclasses  since I am using libraries that my have the same dunder methods overwritten etc. But I looked at the dataclasses code and made a solution based on it myself (see other answer)

Based on Alex proposed Solution I went trough the dataclass code and build the following decorator to solve my issue:
def create_init(args, body, *, globals=None, locals=None,
           return_type=None):
    # Note that we mutate locals when exec() is called.  Caller
    # beware!  The only callers are internal to this module, so no
    # worries about external callers.
    if locals is None:
        locals = {}
    return_annotation = '->None'
    args = ','.join(args)
    body = '\n'.join(f'  {b}' for b in body)

    # Compute the text of the entire function.
    txt = f' def __init__(self,* ,{args}){return_annotation}:\n{body}'

    local_vars = ', '.join(locals.keys())
    txt = f"def __create_fn__({local_vars}):\n{txt}\n return __init__"
    ns = {}
    exec(txt, globals, ns)
    return ns['__create_fn__'](**locals)


def make_signature(cls):
    bases = cls.mro()[1:-1][::-1]
    final_parameters = []
    for base in bases:
        parameters = signature(base.__init__).parameters
        # get all parameters that are not self or kwargs
        parameters = [name for name, param in parameters.items() if name not in ['self', 'kwargs']]
        final_parameters.extend(parameters)

    assert len(final_parameters) == len(set(final_parameters)), "Duplicate parameters found"
    d = [f"{p}={p}" for p in final_parameters]
    body = [f"super().__init__(self,{','.join(d)})"]
    globas = sys.modules[cls.__module__].__dict__
    init_function  = create_init(final_parameters, body,globals=globas)
    init_function.__qualname__ = f"{cls.__qualname__}.{init_function.__name__}"
    init_function.__text_signature__ = str(signature(init_function))
    setattr(cls, '__init__', init_function)

    return cls

However e.g. pycharms parameter info does not work apparently with it see this comment
So in order for the user to get the signature I add the following to the  make_signature method:
def get_init_signature(cls):
    sign =  signature(cls.__init__)
    pretty_sign = str(sign)
    return pretty_sign

get_init_signature = classmethod(get_init_signature)

cls.get_init_signature = get_init_signature

than print(Derived.get_init_signature()) returns the signature for the user
